# Remove "Joomla! Hosting from cloudaccess.net" in CloudBase3 template

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I've installed CloudBase3 template, and in the footer I can see the message "Joomla Hosting from CloudAccess.net".

How can I remove this message?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also modify the code directly by opening the file 
`../templates/cloudbase3/features/branding.php` using your favorite php editor.

At lines 21-24 you will see this code :

```
<div class="rt-block branding">
    <span>Joomla! Hosting from</span>
    <a href="http://www.cloudaccess.net/products/joomla-hosting-support.html" title="ClodAccess.net Joomla Hosting" class="powered-by"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch pal... It basically makes my answer more theoretical and less complete, but I didn't have access to template's source code, was looking only at it's demo site. Then again, who could possibly have access to all these thousands of Joomla templates over the years...

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with the template too. And yes, who would possibly have access to thousands of Joomla templates over the years... lol. But I remember I have a free joomla installation with cloudaccess.net and quickly browse the files. Doing a 'Search All' show me that code :)

Comment: I've commented the two lined inside the div and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From what can be seen by Firebug at [Cloudbase3 Template Demo site](http://cloudbase30.cloudaccess.net/), it is obvious that copyright message in the footer is actually module with class `branding`, probably of type Custom HTML.

By examining module positions via link `http://cloudbase30.cloudaccess.net/?tp=1`, it can be seen that the module is in position `copyright-a`, so in order to disable that message, you should go to Module Manager at `Extensions | Modules` , click on 'Search Tools' button, in 'Select Position' dropdown select that position `copyright-a`, find the module in question and either disable it or delete it.

Comment: I don't have this position in the search filter and I've no modules with copyright. I've the standatd `BreadCumbs`, `Main Menu` and `Login Form` and another two that I've created.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that after @webchun gave correct answer by having access to source code, which I hadn't. That's the beauty of community such as JSE is... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Module Manager at Extensions | Modules , 
click on 'Search Tools' button, in 'Select Position'
 dropdown select that position copyright-a,
 find the module in question and either disable it or delete it.